# Ember return only custom endpoint payload

Tags: ember.js, datastore, endpoint, payload

Good day

I am making a call to a custom endpoint, then I make a pushpayload but how I return only the records that are in the payload and not all records from store.
I know there is a solution in version 2.5 of ember but I'm using 2.4

How should the workflow or functions I use?

Update 1:

Here is the code:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        let adapter = this.store.adapterFor('category');
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            // Calling a custom endpoint
            products: adapter.products(params.category_id).then((response)=>{
                this.store.pushPayload('product', response);
                return this.store.peekAll('product');
                //Here is the problem.. i want just the payload records and no all records from store
            })
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the solution in 2.5?

Comment: Please can you try to provide more detail, e.g. the code?

Comment: @vikram7 I think the questions' author refers to `ds-pushpayload-return` more detail here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480907/ember-return-only-custom-endpoint-payload

Comment: Sorry wrong link https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4213

Comment: Why do you call the adapter manually?

Comment: Because I'm calling to a custom endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the ids from response and than build map over the ids and get the records by `peekRecord` or filter the result of `peekAll` by ids. Both seems to be hacky, but since `ds-pushpayload-return` will be included in next ember data release it might be enough for your use case.